# Make image appears when user scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I have a very long html page, with a lot of things.
I want that an image in a div appears when user scroll down the page and reach the div.

The appartition will be managed whith the css property transition:opacity
But I don't understand how to trigger the effect.

Comment: try: http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

Comment: Search for "lazy loading".

Answer (score 0):

exemple

CSS

```
.imageToAppear{display:none;opacity:0}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wantedonscroll"></div>
<div id="imageToAppear"><img src="/01.png"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$( "#wantedonscroll" ).scroll(function() {
 $("#imageToAppear").fadeIn();
});
```

you can costumize the fade in event here is documentation [Jquery Fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

thank your for your answer :)

But it just don't work in my html page...

this is my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#imageToAppear{display:none;opacity:0}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<p>Lorem ispum .... and a lot of things in order to have something to scroll</p>
</div>
<div id="wantedonscroll"></div>
<div id="imageToAppear"><img src="test.png"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#wantedonscroll").scroll(function() {
 $("#imageToAppear").fadeIn();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is wrong with it?